# Is it possible in Acumatica to export list of branches using SOAP API

Tags: acumatica

I would like to export a list of branches defined for a company in Acumatica. The export should include a check if the option of using branches is enabled.

Objects Branch or Company are not listed in Acumatica WSDL.

Is it possible to export this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to extend the default endpoint to add the Company entity, and within this entity, you can add the Branches entity.  Once that is done, you should be able to access it, assuming that the login credentials you are using to connect to the API has permissions to see this information.[image]

Comment: Thank you Diane. What is the reason that access in not included into the Default endpoint?

Comment: I am not sure why it is not in the default.  There are various entities missing from the default endpoint, and with each release, Acumatica adds more that were missing before.

Comment: Alexander, if this answered your question, I would appreciate it if you would please mark it as answered.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Diane, yes you answered the question. I already clicked on the top arrow to mark it as useful, and not sure how to mark it as a complete answer. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: According to Stackoverflow:   Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: Thank you Diane again for another helpful tip! Your answer marked as accepted with great appreciation.